# USB Flash Drive found, but not mounted

Tags: usb, mount, 22.04

My Flash USB stopped working recently, though nothing was done to it during this period. Looks like it's detected, but then can't be mounted properly.

Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS

```
udevadm monitor

KERNEL[554.700306] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-6 (usb)
KERNEL[554.765191] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-6/2-6:1.0 (usb)
KERNEL[554.765360] add      /devices/virtual/workqueue/scsi_tmf_3 (workqueue)
KERNEL[554.765383] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-6/2-6:1.0/host3 (scsi)
KERNEL[554.765400] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-6/2-6:1.0/host3/scsi_host/host3 (scsi_host)
KERNEL[554.765446] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-6/2-6:1.0 (usb)
KERNEL[554.765499] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-6 (usb)
UDEV  [554.766801] add      /devices/virtual/workqueue/scsi_tmf_3 (workqueue)
UDEV  [554.770904] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-6 (usb)
UDEV  [554.774023] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-6/2-6:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [554.775406] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-6/2-6:1.0/host3 (scsi)
UDEV  [554.776911] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-6/2-6:1.0/host3/scsi_host/host3 (scsi_host)
UDEV  [554.779796] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-6/2-6:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [554.784268] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-6 (usb)
KERNEL[575.637562] change   /devices/virtual/thermal/thermal_zone8 (thermal)
KERNEL[575.637603] change   /devices/virtual/thermal/thermal_zone8 (thermal)
UDEV  [575.638923] change   /devices/virtual/thermal/thermal_zone8 (thermal)
UDEV  [575.639472] change   /devices/virtual/thermal/thermal_zone8 (thermal)
KERNEL[590.997688] change   /devices/virtual/thermal/thermal_zone8 (thermal)
KERNEL[590.997715] change   /devices/virtual/thermal/thermal_zone8 (thermal)
UDEV  [590.999007] change   /devices/virtual/thermal/thermal_zone8 (thermal)
UDEV  [590.999597] change   /devices/virtual/thermal/thermal_zone8 (thermal)
KERNEL[599.509711] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-6/2-6:1.0/host3/scsi_host/host3 (scsi_host)
KERNEL[599.509748] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-6/2-6:1.0/host3 (scsi)
UDEV  [599.511261] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-6/2-6:1.0/host3/scsi_host/host3 (scsi_host)
UDEV  [599.511892] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-6/2-6:1.0/host3 (scsi)
KERNEL[599.541498] remove   /devices/virtual/workqueue/scsi_tmf_3 (workqueue)
KERNEL[599.541603] unbind   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-6/2-6:1.0 (usb)
KERNEL[599.541660] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-6/2-6:1.0 (usb)
KERNEL[599.541804] unbind   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-6 (usb)
KERNEL[599.541872] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-6 (usb)
UDEV  [599.542276] remove   /devices/virtual/workqueue/scsi_tmf_3 (workqueue)
UDEV  [599.545233] unbind   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-6/2-6:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [599.547588] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-6/2-6:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [599.550176] unbind   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-6 (usb)
UDEV  [599.552479] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-6 (usb)
```

And

```
dmesg

[  554.685478] usb 2-6: new SuperSpeed USB device number 11 using xhci_hcd
[  554.707751] usb 2-6: New USB device found, idVendor=090c, idProduct=1000, bcdDevice=11.00
[  554.707754] usb 2-6: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  554.707756] usb 2-6: Product: Flash Drive
[  554.707757] usb 2-6: Manufacturer: Samsung
[  554.707758] usb 2-6: SerialNumber: 03765190700241213213
[  554.772781] usb-storage 2-6:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[  554.772979] scsi host3: usb-storage 2-6:1.0
[  581.533226] usb 2-6: Disable of device-initiated U1 failed.
[  586.657281] usb 2-6: Disable of device-initiated U2 failed.
[  592.029554] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[  597.405306] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[  597.613336] usb 2-6: device not accepting address 11, error -62
[  597.828420] usb 2-6: Device not responding to setup address.
[  598.040253] usb 2-6: Device not responding to setup address.
[  598.245388] usb 2-6: device not accepting address 11, error -71
[  598.456149] usb 2-6: Device not responding to setup address.
[  598.668297] usb 2-6: Device not responding to setup address.
[  598.873213] usb 2-6: device not accepting address 11, error -71
[  599.084234] usb 2-6: Device not responding to setup address.
[  599.296283] usb 2-6: Device not responding to setup address.
[  599.501252] usb 2-6: device not accepting address 11, error -71
[  599.517374] usb 2-6: USB disconnect, device number 11
[  599.756640] usb 2-6: Device not responding to setup address.
[  599.967881] usb 2-6: Device not responding to setup address.
[  600.173348] usb 2-6: device not accepting address 12, error -71
[  600.384173] usb 2-6: Device not responding to setup address.
[  600.596336] usb 2-6: Device not responding to setup address.
[  600.805266] usb 2-6: device not accepting address 13, error -71
[  600.813594] usb usb2-port6: attempt power cycle
[  601.752173] usb 2-6: Device not responding to setup address.
[  601.964252] usb 2-6: Device not responding to setup address.
[  602.169734] usb 2-6: device not accepting address 14, error -71
[  602.384374] usb 2-6: Device not responding to setup address.
[  602.596608] usb 2-6: Device not responding to setup address.
[  602.801356] usb 2-6: device not accepting address 15, error -71
[  602.809420] usb usb2-port6: unable to enumerate USB device
```

The weirdest thing for me is that Manufacturer, SN and some other service info is detected, but then it doesn't work. Is there a chance it's a programmatic error or it's likely that my drive is gone?

Comment: How was the drive formatted? Does it work on a Windows (or MacOS) computer? You may want to try the `chkdsk` command in Windows if it is formatted to work with Windows.

Comment: @user68186 exFAT. Tested on 2 different Windows laptops. On one of them it's fine, on another it's similar to Ubuntu, but that one is old.

Comment: It is better to fix Windows fine systems in Windows. The USB drive may be dying/dead.